# Usercreated column in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Imagine you have a column called

```
usercreated = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
```

And you want this field to automaticly filled when first putted to store. Like this did for auto_date. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_default_value), your best bet is going to be a redefinition of the property class you're working with in order to override the default_value() method. You could also try duckpunching, though it's probably not a viable option.

Answer (score 3):

The User property type has an `auto_current_user` flag, which is an easy solution if your using google accounts for authentication.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#UserProperty

Comment: right, I simply use my own. And already create the same implement, as they do, only for Reference